# How to repeatedly call asynchronous function until specified timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to keep calling asnchronous api requests repeatedly until it exceeds specified time. Using async-retry we can only specify retrycount  and interval, we wanted to specify even timeout in the parameter.
Can you just suggest a way?

```
// try calling apiMethod 3 times, waiting 200 ms between each retry
async.retry({times: 3, interval: 200}, apiMethod, function(err, result) {
    // do something with the result
});
```

Comment: 3 times in a 200ms interval seems like a 600ms timeout to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want :

```js
const scheduleTrigger = (futureDate) => {
    const timeMS = new Date(futureDate) - new Date();

    return new Promise((res, ref) => {
        if (timeMS > 0) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                res();
            }, timeMS);
        } else {
            rej();
        }
    })
}

//const futureDate = '2020-07-23T20:53:12';
// or
const futureDate = new Date();
futureDate.setSeconds(futureDate.getSeconds() + 5);

console.log('now');

scheduleTrigger(futureDate).then(_ => {
    console.log('future date reached');
    // start whatever you want
    stopFlag = false;
}).catch(_ => {
    // the date provided was in the past
});

const wait = (ms = 2000) => {
    return new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(_ => {
            res();
        }, ms);
    })
}
const asyncFn = _ => Promise.resolve('foo').then(x => console.log(x));
let stopFlag = true;
(async () => {
    while (stopFlag) {
        await asyncFn();
        await wait();
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to keep retrying for as long as its within a certain timeout? How about this:

```js
// Allow retry until the timer runs out
let retry = true;
const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  // Set retry to false to disabled retrying
  retry = false;

  // Can also build in a cancel here
}, 10000); // 10 second timeout

const retryingCall = () => {
  apiMethod()
    .then(response => {
      // Optionally clear the timeout
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // If retry is still true, retry this function again
      if (retry) {
        retryingCall();
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: You don't need a `setTimeout` for this that toggles a `retry` flag, you could just check `if (Date.now() > start + 10000)`

Comment: True! Set a `const start = new Date()` before the retryingCall and check in the catch

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with this function:

```
const retryWithTimeout = ({ timeout, ...retryOptions}, apiMethod, callback) => {
  let timedout = false;
  const handle = setTimeout(
    () => (timedout = true, callback(new Error('timeout'))),
    timeout
  );

  return async.retry(
    retryOptions, 
    innerCallback => timedout || apiMethod(innerCallback),
    (err, result) => timedout || (clearTimeout(handle), callback(err, result))
  )
};
```

It has the advantage of allowing you to use the functionality of `async.retry`, as you apparently want, and also allows the timeout to take place even when what exceeds the timeout is the apiMethod itself, not the waiting time.

Usage example:

```
retryWithTimeout( 
  {timeout: 305, times: 4, interval: 100}, 
  (callback) => { callback('some api error'); },
  (err, result) => console.log('result', err, result)
)
```